# Spring 3 JSR-286 (portlets) docs

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, portlet, jsr286

I know that `Spring 3` supports `JSR-286` (portlets version '2.0').

However I can't find a lot of documentation on that.

Can anyone share some links about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a couple tutorials

[Hello Wold using Spring 3 MVC-Portlets](http://books.dzone.com/articles/hello-world-portlet-using-Spring-3-portlet-MVC)

[pring 3.0 Portlet MVC – Part II (Annotations)](http://books.dzone.com/articles/spring-30-portlet-mvc-part-2)

Also a book in progress [Portlets In Action](http://manning.com/sarin/)

Answer (score 0):

You might find the [Spring 3 API](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/) helpful, specifically the [org.springframework.web.portlet.mvc Package](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/package-summary.html). Listed in the Interface summary section are some Portlet 2.0 interfaces, namely:

- [EventAwareController](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/EventAwareController.html)
- [ResourceAwareController](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/portlet/mvc/ResourceAwareController.html)

This should be enough to get you started.